# Why does the Objective-C Compiler return a "y" as a "0" but then skips over the "if input==0" section?

Tags: objective-c

```
int side1test;
NSLog(@"Is your triangle setup as in an Angle-Side-Angle? (Use 1 for Yes and 0 for No.)");
scanf(" %i", &side1test);
```

Returns "0" when the user enters a "y." However,

```
    if (side1test != 1 && side1test != 0){
        NSLog(@"Please use a '1' for YES and '0' for NO.");
    }
```

Then does not catch.

The program drops into my else clause, and outputs all the NSLogs, skipping the scanf() commands, taking each of them as "0." What is wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by return? scanf returns number of successful input which is different from side1test's value.

Comment: When I later type `NSLog(@" %i", side1test)`, the output is 0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a c++ dev but from googling that function returns the number of valid matches. If it returns 0 you should assume invalid input. side1test has not been set which is why it's 0.

Your code should probably be:--

```
int side1test; 
NSLog(@"Is your triangle setup as in an Angle-Side-Angle? (Use 1 for Yes and 0 for No.)"); 
int result = 0;
while (result==0)
{
    result =scanf(" %i", &side1test);
}
 if (side1test != 1 && side1test != 0){
        NSLog(@"Please use a '1' for YES and '0' for NO.");
   }
```

Comment: If I approached it this way, if the user inputted "0" for "no," wouldn't it prompt him/her again? How does one answer No then?

Comment: 0 would be a valid input so the result would be 1, but side1test would have a value of 0. The biggest issue is if the users enter 2. This would result in a valid result, but your side1test would have an invalid value of 2. However this is detected by your nslog.